# How to implement TextWatcher for EditText for input type License Key with "-" seperator?

Tags: java, android

I want "-" seperator to come automatically when user types in 4th character.My input type is something like this,

> abc2-12fd-asdc-34wq-sd22

When user types in "abc2" the "-" should come there automatically.
Right now I am using this,

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() > 0 && (s.length() % 5) == 0) {
                final char c = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
                if (space == c) {
                    s.delete(s.length() - 1, s.length());
                }
            }
            if (s.length() > 0 && (s.length() % 5) == 0) {
                char c = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
                s.insert(s.length() - 1, String.valueOf(space));
            }

        }
```

But this seems to work fine only with digits. If I type in some alphanumeric input it misses "-" sometimes.

Comment: Use this https://github.com/santalu/mask-edittext it's really easy

Comment: I tried using masked edit text, but the thing is I want "-" coming dynamically when user types in 5th character. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: in the mask you can do this #####-#### the # represents any character and it is a wildcard. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should limit your `Edittext` with only numeric values. To do this, add `android:inputType="number"` to your `Edittext`.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding. Can you describe little more what your problem is? When i tried your code, I saw that only '-' char is missing.